# Change elements position when browser changes size

Tags: css, html

I have 2 `<label>` in the right corner of `div` which located in the center of browser with width/height is 200px/200px. When i change browser size my labels disappears in the right side of browser. How can i make that labels moves to the right side when browser size is changes? I try to make:

```
.my_label{
  position:absolute;
  right: 20px;
}
```

But `right` property is right from the browser window, not from the div.

I need that labels move only when it disappears with browser.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add jsfiddle.net code example.

Answer (score 3):

As George stated, make the parent `position:relative` to have your child element's position be absolute in relation to the containing element (instead of the window).

If you really want to tweak your CSS based on browser size / res, read up on CSS media queries:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: If i setup `position:relative` for parrent element and start to change size of browser window, labels aren't move.

Comment: I see, well that's going to be a problem.  You will either need to use a relative width (like 100% instead of 1000px), use javascript and change the CSS width when the browser is resized, or use Media Queries to dynamically tweak your CSS based on browser sizes.